# Spring inbound integration on cluster mode

Tags: spring, spring-integration, load-balancing

we are using spring inbound polling adapter to check for a file and process it. Problem is process is running multiple nodes in cluster mode. Our Test environment is using load balancing with two nodes, the requirement is to start this polling process on one node. How can we achieve this without creating two war files..? We are not supposed to use XML configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose Spring Integration provides `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` which you should configure with same shared external `MetadataStore`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#metadata-store

**EDIT**

As Gary suggested, you can control `autoStartup` for the Inbound Channel Adapter.

I tested it like :

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    System.setProperty("integrationAllowed", "false");
}

...

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "flow1.input", autoStartup = "${integrationAllowed}", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "100"))
public MessageSource<?> integerMessageSource() {
```

Works well.

The expression `${integrationAllowed}` represent property-placeholder sentence.

If you can't use some shared persistence resource to control the cluster state, than it doesn't look like a cluster...

Comment: Thank you for the direction .. currently we are not using any metadata store, I will explore in this direction.

Comment: You can also use [Leadership Election](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#endpoint-roles) with zookeeper so that only one instance is running at a time. You can also use a system property (for the autoStartup property) and only start one; you can use some external monitor to stop/start instances as needed, perhaps using JMX.

Comment: I tried with System properties, for some reason its not working as expected.  Created a ENV variable integrationAllowed = true and in application using it like this                           @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "fileInputChannel", autoStartup = "#{systemProperties['integrationAllowed']}" , poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "1000"))

Comment: Well, Messaging Annotations don't support SpEL, but Properties Placeholder fits good to your requirements `autoStartup = "${integrationAllowed}"`

Comment: Tried property place holder , but as annotation attributes take only constants , I am not able to use it .. and I am not able to inject property value in to final static variable

Comment: And I can not use MetaData Sharing or ZooKeeper in my application as it requires lot of approvals

Comment: Please, find an EDIT in my asnwer

Comment: you are Correct, our QA systems are not in cluster , they have load-balancing with 2 nodes and our production is cluster env.  Looks like I am doing some stupid mistake here .. I am always getting this error   Could not resolve placeholder 'integrationAllowed' in string value "${integrationAllowed}"

Comment: Try to add `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` `@Bean`. See an edit to my code snippet above.

Comment: create new component with post construct to set the system property ..Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi @Artem Bilan, I have one more question .. I need to create another file poller in same application .. I have copied the same code into different class and getting  Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application:sample.fileInputChannelSAP'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers

Comment: That means that you don't have any consumer on that channel. Your polled produces messages but there is nothing to handle them from that channel