# Can Spring Integration be used in Mutli Server Environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, integration, multiserver

Can we use Spring Integration to configure directory polling for files such that -

With 2 servers configured, polling occurs on 1 server and corresponding processing get distributed b/w both the servers.

Also, can we switch the polling on either of the servers on runtime ?

**Edit -**
Tried configuring JBDC MetaStore and run the two instances separately, able to poll and process but getting intermittently **DeadLockLoserDataAccessException**

Configuration below

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel fileInputChannel(){
return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean(PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata defaultPoller(){
PollerMetadata pollermetadata = new PollerMetadata();
pollermetadata.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(-1);
pollermetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(1000));
return pollermetadata;
}

@Bean
@InBoundChannelAdapter(value = "fileInputChannel"){
FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
source.setDirectory("Mylocalpath");
FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter acceptOnce = new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter();
ChainFileListFilter<File> chainFilter = ChainFileListFilter(".*\\.txt"));
chainFilter.addFilter(acceptOnce);
source.setFilter(chainFilter);
source.setUseWatchService(true);
source.setWatchEvents(FileReadingMessageSource.WatchEventType.CREATE,FileReadingMessageSource.WatchEventType.MODIFY);
return source;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow processFileFlow(){
return IntegrationFlows.from("fileInputChannel")
.handle(service).get();
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean to run in a cluster. Answer yes, but you need to set infrastructure to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662400/spring-inbound-integration-on-cluster-mode

Answer (score 0):

It is really one of the features of Spring Integration to easy implement a distributed solution. You just need add a messaging middle ware into your cluster infrastructure and have all the nodes connected to some destination for sending and receiving. A good example could be a `SubscribableJmsChannel` which you just simple can declare in your application context and all the nodes of your cluster are going to subscribe to this channel for round-robin consumption from JMS queue. It already wouldn't matter which node produces to this channel.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jms.html#jms-channel.

Another sample of similar distributed channels are: AMQP, Kafka, Redis, ZeroMQ.

You also can have a shared message store and use it in the `QueueChannel` definition: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#message-store

Comment: Actually I do not want to configure and use and JMS/Queue channel, I wanted to configure something like this.

Two Servers A & B in distributed Environment. (A directory to be polled for files to be processed)
At Runtime - Single Server (A/B) should poll the directory and whatever consecutive processing should get distributed b/w both servers A and B.

Comment: How can it be distributed without some network interaction ? If single server polls, only that one can process. To let other server be involved , you need to send something over the network. What is your idea?

Comment: Yeah....For HA, trying to setup on two servers, configured JDBC Meta Store, able to poll files from both the servers, but in-between getting this exception DeadLockLoserDataAccessException. seems need to configure Transaction management explicitly, I checked but could not find how can we configure it using Java Annotations instead of XML

Comment: Show, please, your configuration in your question

Comment: Updated configuration in question above. please have a look

Comment: I don’t see any JDBC-related code in your configuration… have may we know where you missing transactions?

Comment: Manually I haven't wrote any JDBC related code, since I have configured FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter with JBDC meta store, it internally checks and finds the record in INT_METADATA_STORE table.

Comment: That’s my point: I don’t see how you use that metadata store. The inbound channel adapter can be configured with transaction j interceptor. However this all doesn’t sound like what you have asked originally. Are you sure that you are on a right track for distributed processing?

Comment: I see entries getting created in the DB MetaStore Table, My aim to process the files from two instances, I see both are processing using this just due to some concurrent transaction DeadLockLoserDataAccessException is coming, due to see something missing here.